# re-size elements in a list based on index

Tags: python

I have a list of lists in python which I'm using to write data an input file for a command line executable.  The executable has limits on the length of SOME of the input strings but not all.  Is there a way to re-size all the elements in a certain position in my 'array' such that:

```
1, test, 12, toronto  
2, test, 145, montreal  
3, test, 178, north bay
```

would become:

```
1, test, 12, to  
2, test, 145, mo  
3, test, 178, no
```

As far as coding I would think something like this would work iteratively, but I would much prefer a way to process a whole array in one go.

```
for x in list:
    x[3] = x[3][:5] #where 5 is the length
```

Comment: First, good night here. :) Second, what is actually your problem? What do you mean by "*process a while array in one go*"?

Comment: Acutally it is "good afternoon" :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a = [ [1, 'test', 12, 'toronto'], [2, 'test', 145, 'montreal'] ]
a = [ [e [:5] if i == 3 else e for i, e in enumerate (line)] for line in a]
print (a)
```

Being `i` the position you want to shorten, if it is various columns, use something like `i in (3, 5)`.

Or if you have different lengths for different columns, you can use something like this:

```
a = [[1, 'test', 12, 'toronto'], [2, 'test', 145, 'montreal']]
shorten = {1: 2, 3: 4} #shorten column 1 to length 2, and col 3 to len 4
a = [[e[:shorten[i]] if i in shorten else e for i, e in enumerate(line)] for line in a]
print (a)
```

Comment: This is perfect.  The added ability to do "i = ( 0 or 2 or 10)" is especially helpful.

Comment: `i = (0 or 2 or 10)` is the same as `i = 2` and won't work as expected. You are looking for `i in (0, 2, 10)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
my_list = [[1, 'test', 12, 'toronto'],
          [2, 'test', 145, 'montreal'],
          [3, 'test', 178, 'north bay']]

print map(lambda x: x[:2] + [x[3][:2]],[x for x in my_list])
```

outputs

```
 [[1, 'test', 12, 'to'], [2, 'test', 145, 'mo'], [3, 'test', 178, 'no']]
```